# sql join one row per column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables as follows:

```
Product GroupSize    
------------------          
1         10                      
2         15                      

GroupSize  Size1  Size2  Size3  Size4   
--------------------------------------
  10       100    200
  15       50     100    300
```

And i want to get a table like this:

```
Product  Size
--------------
   1      100
   1      200
   2      50
   2      100
   2      300
```

How can I do this in SQL?

Comment: (1) What database are you using?  Please tag the question appropriately.  (2) Where does `product` = `3` come from?  It is not in your sample data.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the final table, there is no product 3. The Database is SQL Server. This is a sample table, but in fact the product table has hundreds of rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The results that you have would come from this query:

```
select 1 as product, size1 as size from table2 where size1 is not null union all
select 2 as product, size2 as size from table2 where size2 is not null union all
select 3 as product, size3 as size from table2 where size3 is not null;
```

This is ANSI standard SQL and should work in any database.

EDIT:

Given the revised question, you can use `CROSS APPLY`, which is easier than the `UNION ALL`:

```
select t1.product, s.size
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.groupsize = t2.groupsize
     cross apply
     (values(t2.size1), (t2.size2), (t2.size3)) as s(size)
where s.size is not null;
```

Comment: Thank you. It works, but "where s.size is not null" is not avoiding the null sizes. It's working with "where s.size <> '' "

Comment: @Jota16 null is not the same as " " empty string. When a value is null you dont know the value however when its empty you know that it is empty. Empty string is basically the equivalent of zero for varchar datatypes. You wouldn't say that zero is not a value, however null is an unknown value.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [Product],Size FROM tbl1
INNER JOIN(

SELECT GroupSize,Size1 Size from tbl2 where Size1 is not null
UNION
SELECT GroupSize,Size2 from tbl2 where Size2 is not null
UNION
SELECT GroupSize,Size3 from tbl2 where Size3 is not null
UNION
SELECT GroupSize,Size4 from tbl2 where Size4 is not null
)table2
ON tbl1.GroupSize=table2.GroupSize
```

Answer (score 0):

`UNPIVOT` version:

```
DECLARE @p TABLE(Product INT, GroupSize INT)
DECLARE @g TABLE(GroupSize INT, Size1 INT, Size2 INT, Size3 INT, Size4 INT)

INSERT INTO @p VALUES
(1, 10),
(2, 15)

INSERT INTO @g VALUES
(10, 100, 200, NULL, NULL),
(15, 50, 100, 300, NULL)


;WITH cte AS(SELECT p.Product, g.* 
             FROM @p p 
             JOIN @g g ON g.GroupSize = p.GroupSize)
SELECT Product, Size 
FROM cte
UNPIVOT(Size FOR col IN([Size1],[Size2],[Size3],[Size4]))u
```